# Can we organize cursor focusing order when press tab key in html form

Tags: html, tabs, cursor, focus

Is there a way to control the cursor next focusing order when pressing TAB Key.
[image]

Here is my UI and it is using different controllers (input(text/number), dropdown). I want control focusing order (when press TAB Key) RequestNo--> Date--> PaymentNo-->PaymentCategory somthing like order. Only I could found way for the  controls

Can anyone suggest me a direction?

Comment: Look up `tabindex`. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change text field selection order when using tab key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165241/how-to-change-text-field-selection-order-when-using-tab-key)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `tabindex` global attribute to specify the keyboard navigation ordering.

For example:

```
<input type="text" name="requestNo" tabindex="1">
<input type="date" name="data" tabindex="2">
<input type="text" name="paymentNumber" tabindex="3">
...
```

You can learn more about `tabindex` in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

Comment: Thanks for your guide. It helped me.